# Junit test with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) fails - "No tests found matching.."

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to figure out the reason of why I'm getting errors when I'm trying to run some tests that were created and did run a while back.  This is the Test class:

```
package com.chw.pxi.impl.oneway.formatter;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class OnewayOldFormatterTestsWhy
{
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
    }

    @Test
    public void
    test_nothing()
    {
        System.out.println("Yep");
    }

}
```

Here is the error when I try to run the "test_nothing" method by right-click, choose "Run As/Junit test".

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test_nothing], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test_nothing(com.chw.pxi.impl.oneway.formatter.OnewayOldFormatterTestsWhy)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.chw.pxi.impl.oneway.formatter.OnewayOldFormatterTestsWhy,fLeadingIdentifier=test_nothing]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@3632be31
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

There are lots of jar files in the build path for this project.  I guess I should try creating a new project and see if the problem follows. A side note - when I run a test on a method in another test that has this - it runs fine without the error above:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"dao-tests-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=true)
//Note: This is a live database test but transactions will be rolled back
//except those that invoke methods that require new transactions
public class AgencyDaoTests
```

If there is additional information needed, please let me know what and how I can go about and get that information for you.

Thanks, Michael

Comment: are you try with another class name? for example: OnewayOldFormatterTest

Comment: The method above was a large Junit test that worked before and I created it.  At first I wasn't quite clear to your suggestion, but renamed the class to another name. Same result.  I've even tried other test classes with the same result.  I've done lots of searches for this problem and have done all the suggestions with no results.  It must be something with my computer as a co-worker is able to run without issues.

Comment: I'd say that the `PowerMockRunner` tries to find all PowerMock values to replace them with its own implementations. It doesn't appear you've set any. Try adding a `@PrepareForTest` annotation with at least one class in it so that it can be picked by the runner…

Answer (score 16):

As for `'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.6.5'` version of Powermock I managed this to work by moving `@PrepareForTest` annotation from method level to class level.

Comment: Great, saved my day! Thx!

Comment: powermock 2.0.0 also encounter this; this solution saved my day!